# Getting 401 error on Megento 2.1.10 using access token with an intergration user

Tags: vb.net, rest, api, magento, soapui

I am a 3rd party developer trying to update stock quantity via access token/integration/REST method and I have run into a 401 error.

I am testing using SoapUI and also through my application I am developing and I get the same error.

VB Code

```
Dim Access_Token = "mXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX4"
Dim WebClient = New WebClient() 
WebClient.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType) = "application/json"
WebClient.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization) = "Authorization Bearer " & Access_Token
Dim Response As String
Response = WebClient.UploadString("http://www.XXXX.com/rest/V1/products/MXXXP/stockItems/1", "Put", "{""stockItem"":{""qty"":100}}")
```

I have setup the integration, give it access to all and activated it to get the access token.

The full error is:

```
{"message":"Consumer is not authorized to access %resources","parameters":{"resources":"Magento_CatalogInventory::cataloginventory"}}
```

Any help would be apricated.
Thanks,
Richard.

Comment: As I cant can any feedback from the web developer or host I created my own Magento site on AWS and was able to update a product using SoapUI. For the VBA I updated the auth header to be `WebClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer 6XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXd")` still dose not work on client site!

Answer (score 0):

In Magento your user role needs to have access to the module. It seems the user you are trying to get authenticated doesn't have access to catalog inventory. Please login to Magento admin, goto System->Permissions->All Users. Here check what is the Role of your User. Then goto System->Permissions->User Roles->Open your Users Role. Check the box of "Catalog". Now get new authentication token for the User & then use this new token for further API calls.
[image: See Image here]

Comment: Thanks, as per my post I have given "access to all" to ensure I am not being blocked. I have heard that on shared hosting environments their maybe additional blocks I am trying to work with developer/hosting provider to find out. Any other ideas let me know :)

Comment: Also the integration is not a user and when "activated" provides a access token which can be used on API queries as per https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html and Integration tokens

Comment: Have you tried with getting authentication token with User account ? See atleast this works. Then we can find out the reason for it.

Comment: Hi Abdul, thanks for your comment. I have tested in code and SoapUI with two admin users with access to all resources. Got access tokens for both then used that as Bearer for accessing the above resource and got the same error back '{
   "message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",
   "parameters": {"resources": "Magento_CatalogInventory::cataloginventory"}
}'